# Supporting graphics for both Retina and non-Retina display

Tags: iphone, retina-display

I wanted to know how I should proceed to support graphics properly on both retina and non-retina display. I have a background image of dimension 640 * 920, I think it is for retina display. But how would I go for supporting non-Retina display having dimension 320*480 ? How do you structure your graphics resources? I have group called "Art" having all graphics (right now all for Retina display dimension).

Will iOS automatically scale down my graphics to non-Retina display? I had one more query, like I am dragging one button to a view on some absolute position for Retina display, will it automatically adjust to appropriate position on devices having dimension 320 * 480? How can I deal with supporting both screen dimensions/resolution?

Note: I am using Xcode 4.3.3 and using storyboards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must make two versions of each image. For example, if you had a 544x151 image for retina, say its called 'background@2x.png', make a 272x75 version for non retina display, which would be 'background.png'

Name all retina images with the suffix "@2x.png". The OS will automatically present the @2x images on retina devices. So to conclude:

272x75 would be "background.png"
544x151 would be "background@2x.png"

This also is the correct way to make icons compatible with retina devices. Just make a 114x114 (iphone) or 144x144 (ipad) and name it "icon@2x.png".

Answer (score 2):

You need to name your retina images with a "@2x.png" suffix.

So if you have an image "pic.png" this should be for non-retina, and "pic@2x.png" should be at retina scale.  You should select the "pic.png" image and not the @2x one when placing it in the storyboard/xib/UIImage.

The storyboard based image will automatically pick the retina image if needed.

Comment: Thanks. Lets say my button image is 544*151 (retina), so do i have to make separate image of different size for non retina ?? Can ios scale it to appropriate size for non-retina, if i give those specific names as u said above ? Or do i have to make separate version of image , ofcourse with name conventions as specified ?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken that would be a 'suffix' rather than a 'prefix'.

Comment: @bloodwing Yes, you need to make a separate image of half size for the non retina display.  For this reason you may want to use even numbers for your retina dimensions (544 x 152) so it is easier to scale to standard (277 x 76), unless you really want them taking up different proportions on each display.