# App rejection 10.6

Tags: iphone

My apps for apple got rejected due to 
as not optimized to support the device screen size and/or resolution.

But it fits the iPhone 4 screen perfectly.
This app isn't universal and this app is for ios5.1 so no iPhone 3g. 
What could it be?

Comment: How does it look on a non-retina device?

Comment: The iPhone 3Gs (and various iPod Touch devices) supports iOS5.1 and doesn't have a retina display.  Do you have both retina and non-retina graphics assets?

Comment: I believe you do. I think this rule was put into effect as of iOS 4+ (iPhone 4 release)

Comment: What rule was put into effect?

Comment: And what if I don't want to support non retina display?

Comment: @josecarlos why did you bump this question with an invalid edit?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm  cancel the edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rejection code 10.6 usually means you're missing retina or non-retina images, which are both now required. See also this post for further info on adding retina images:

[Supporting graphics for both Retina and Non Retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553914/supporting-graphics-for-both-retina-and-non-retina-display)

Comment: Must it be like this for all images or just the one they showed a screenshot of? And also, do i have to resize it, or do i just add @2x and it will automatically do it (confused about that part).

Comment: I know that the splash (default) and icon images must have both a retina and non retina version. I believe that all other images are supposed to have both versions too, but it may depend on the reviewer for these. Your best bet is to have retina and non retina images for all images. Further, retina images must be twice the width and height of the regular image (you can't just rename them because if you do, they will likely appear funny, possibly at half expected size).