# Is mandatory to use retina image in iphone apps?

Tags: iphone, retina-display, ui-design

I have developed a application with non retina images. While submitting the icon and screenshots in iTunes connect we have to provide retina (2x)images. Whether it is mandatory to include 2x images for all the images in the app or it can be optional. Please guide me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336809/app-rejection-10-6

Comment: @Bourne: review guideline 10.6 doesn't mention about retina and non-retina.

Answer (score 2):

While it is not mandatory for all images, you should provide retina images. since you need to upload all screen shots from retina devices. iPhones that are now sold are all retina devices (iPhone 4/4S and iPhone 5), suppling non retina images for older devices and iPad 2/Mini would be generally be a good idea.
Apple may reject your app if it does not contain retina version of app UI images, they will say that your does fully support the latest device. I've have had this happen with an iPad app which did not support retina and some image with text became very blurry.

If you did not use any retina images the screen shots will not look very crisp and ,might even look blurry. The app icon should support most sizes, even iPad and iPad retina even if it is an iPhone app.

But images which you, for example, download from the internet or some other external source don't have to be retina. But again if possible they should be since this will increase the user experience.

Comment: In itunes connect it is mandatory, so i have given retina images. But the app doesnot include any retina image. Will apple reject app for this reason?

Comment: I just updated an old, non-retina app with bug fixes. We don't have the time resources to spare right now 'retinizing' it, but we were able to submit the new binary without providing retina or 4-inch screenshots (but the 1024x1024 icon was compulsory). I wonder if it will be rejected...

Comment: You will just have to wait and see, but I don't think your app will be rejected if it is an update. I just had a rejection once of an app that dit not support retina. Since then we do all our app with retina support.

Answer (score 1):

Apple’s not requiring that all the images inside your app be retina, just that the screenshot be 2x. So, no worries: if you're trying to submit the app you just need the screenshot to be 2x, the app won't be rejected for not having retina images.